# Returning Id's from a list in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

I'm having an issue with Entity Framework, when I execute SaveChanges, the context has quite a few objects associated with it, some of the objects are updated and some are added, afterwards I want to use the Id's of all these items (the Id's for the added items are only assigned on insert in the database). After the save changes a list of all the objects is empty.

I've seen samples on the site where the object is updated after the save so I suspect it might be how I'm getting the list of objects in the first place

Here's my code:

```
// Lots of processing to create or update objects 
using (var localContext = this.context)
{
    var updatedObjects = localContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.Entity is GenerationEvent && (e.State == EntityState.Modified || e.State == EntityState.Added));
    var updatedEvents = updatedObjects.Select(e => (GenerationEvent)e.Entity);

    // The list has 5 items in at this point
    localContext.SaveChanges();

    // This list is now empty
    DoSomethingWithList(updatedEvents);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `updatedEvents` is not a `list`, but Linq query which is reexecuted anytime you enumerate it. if you want to cache it for latter use, put `.ToList()` at the end of the `updateEvents` assignment line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `updatedEvents` is a Linq query. Linq queries aren't executed immediately. By the time it is executed in your code it won't find any updated object anymore. Putting `.ToList()` after the Linq query will execute it immediately.

```
var updatedEvents = updatedObjects.Select(e => (GenerationEvent)e.Entity).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

first your "using" statement is odd.
it should be

```
using (var context = new MyContext()) //passing in optional connection string.
{

}
```

Then the way you access your entities seem odd or i have no clue what you are doing there...

```
var updatedObjects = localContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.Entity is GenerationEvent && (e.State == EntityState.Modified || e.State == EntityState.Added));
var updatedEvents = updatedObjects.Select(e => (GenerationEvent)e.Entity);
```

Seems like you are asking the context for all items which are considered "Add" or "Updated"

Then you are accepting the changes to the context. eg SaveChanges().

I fully expect "updatedEvents" to be empty, after save-changes is called.

Change you stuff... to something like

```
using (var context = new MyContext()) //passing in optional connection string.
{
    LIst<EntityType> listOfChangedEntities = //ToDo:either passed in or generated
    context.EntityType.AddRandge(listOfChangedEntities);
    context.SaveChanges();

    //after SaveChanges has been done all the entities in the 
    //listOfChangedEntities will now have there id's

    //for update, fetch the entities... change them and Update them

}
```

I suspect that you are trying to create some sort of generic code to handle any type of Entity without specifying its type. Your code is not suited for this as it is, if this is what you are trying to do, I would modify the question to ask what you are trying to achieve. But the above is the Normal way of getting the Id's of the entities which have been inserted.

The other examples you are passably talking about is where they use foreign keys and navigation properties to automatically associate related entities, but your code looks way off from that.

**UPDATE**

---

routine

```
public static DoWork()
{
   var context = new MyContext();  

   List<GenerationEvent > internalEntityType = new List<GenerationEvent ();
   foreach(var item in SomeList)
   {
        var newItemEntity = new GenerationEvent();
        newItemEntity.Name = "Test";
        context.GenerationEvent.Add(newItemEntity);

        //add to internal list
        internalEntityType.Add(newItemEntity )
   }
   context.SaveChanges();

   var first_id = internalEntityType.FirstOrDefault().Id;
   //first_id will not be 0 it will be the Id the database gave it.
}
```

Comment: The problem I was having is that the routine that updates and creates new objects (in this case the GenerationEvent object) is long and complicated, I can't pass the list in at the end and update and add them there. The line of code you queried, queries the context itself, which has already had the objects amended or added on it, and returns a list of all object (OK after the .ToList() suggested by Venerik) of the GenerationEvent type in a state of modified or added.

Comment: OK...  interested in what your doing, could you explain more... i know you have solved it. Just trying to understand why? I mean why are you doing it like this..., I see you are interested in an entity called GenerationEvent which are obviously updated and add in a sub routine... and you want them out. I would just add them to an "internal list" in the routine... then they would be updated with the ids you want when savechanges is called. How would that not work. It's way less complicated.

Comment: Yeah its a little odd. They've completely changed how the system is architected, while adding a whole hunk of extra functionality. Previously the system took and input from a web service, and added or updated event details to a local db, then a partial class of the entity object had a method to generate a complex XML document that was then ftp'd off  somewhere else. I've been asked to make this now send a different document to a different location, and the architect has specified separating out this processing with a service bus between the 2 service. Would have done it differently originally!